# Do metals at low temperature follow Ohm's law?

Tags: electric-current, electrical-resistance, superconductivity, metals, low-temperature-physics

I think metals at low temperature do not follow Ohm's because of superconductivity. Is it true? What about metals at high temperature?

Comment: Not every material becomes a superconductor. Also : what is 'low temperature'?

Comment: Ohm's law does not apply to superconductors, so when a metal becomes a superconductor Ohm's law no longer applies. But as long as the metal isn't superconducting Ohm's law will apply regardless of the temperature, though of course the resistance of a metal does vary with temperature.

Comment: Ohms low not only doesn't work at low temperature, but also doesn't work at high temperature and low and high current. Almost every formular have a range of working conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ohm's law describes the observed relationship between the voltage ($V$) applied across a simple conductor and the resulting current ($I$) flowing through it.

Georg Ohm found by experiment that $I$ is directly proportional to $V$ for a particular length of wire.
The formula $V = I R$ where $R$ is the "resistance to current flow" of the conductor describes the relationship he found.
Later the unit of resistance was named (in recognition of his work) as the Ohm. (A 1 Ohm resistor will conduct 1 Amp when 1 Volt is applied across it.)

For a purely resistive material where there are no other complicating factors such as changing magnetic fields, electrochemical or semiconducting junctions, etc. then Ohm's law holds for all conductors including superconductors.

Be aware that the resistance of most conductors changes a bit with temperature, but current and/or voltage will also change so that $V=IR$ remains true.

Also be aware that any inductance or capacitance in the circuit will affect the current/voltage relationship if there is alternating current present.

Superconductivity is a property shown by some materials (e.g. some but not all  metals, some compounds, some allotropes of carbon) where they abruptly lose all resistance below a particular critical temperature.

For many of these materials the critical temperature is somewhere near absolute zero (-273 °C), but a few materials have been found that do this at higher temperatures, some even above the boiling point of liquid nitrogen (-196 °C), which makes experiments easier to conduct without special super-cooling equipment.

Above the critical temperature they revert to having their normal resistivity again.

Superconductors will suddenly stop superconducting if the current density becomes too high, so they cannot carry infinite current.
An electric current through a loop of superconducting wire can persist indefinitely with no power source.
[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superconductivity]

**Superconductors have zero resistance**, so a current flowing in a superconductor will drop zero Volts

i.e. $V = I * 0 = 0$,  so **Ohm's law still holds for a superconductor**.

Comment: You're contradicting yourself when you say that superconductors obey Ohm's law. You said Ohm found out that voltage is directly proportional to current, which is true. So if the voltage is zero, so must current. But in a superconductor carrying current, the current is not zero, even though the voltage is. So superconductors don't follow Ohm's law, unlike what you said.

Answer (score 0):

Resistivity usually increases with temperature, because electrons collide with more obstacles if there are many vibrations.

If you decrease temperature, resistivity decerases. However, at very low temperature (closer to $0K$), even though there are fewer vibrations, resistivity usually stops decreasing and remains constant. That's because metals are usually non-pure crystals. The more impurities, the more obstacles, so the more resistivity. A change in purity can lead to several orders of magnitude of increasing/decreasing resistivity at low temperature. Howver, this effect is quickly masked if you raise the temperature.

This is the general case for metals, but each element is different. For example, $Bi$ has extremely weird properties.

Superconductors are those whose "constant resistivity near 0K" suddenly falls down.

Answer (score -3):

First you should clarify what you mean by low temperature, if you go to definition of ohm, s law (at constant temperature and pressure voltage is directly proportional to current) u will see yes it does change with temperature but ohms law is not universal it applies to certain cases only when we say superconductors I am unsure that wether ohm, s can clearly depict picture, Ohm's 'Law' is somewhat of a misnomer, because it is not really a universal law because it only applies to a small range of conductors. Ohm's Law only applies when the ratio of voltage to current is constant for variations in voltage. Devices that follow Ohm's Law are called linear or ohmic; those that don't are called non-linear or non-Ohmic. Most metal conductors are linear, but some are not. For example, tungsten does not obey Ohm's Law because its ratio of voltage to current changes as the voltage applied across it changes -in other words, tungsten is non-linear devices, Electronics devices such as diodes, electrolytes, and gases are all non-linear and do not obey Ohm's Law. Having said that, the ratio of voltage to current will always tell you what the resistance of a device devices, such as diodes, electrolytes, and gases are all non-linear and do not obey Ohm's Law
Edit:) tungsten does obey ohm, s law but in bulb it has variable temperature. So yes it disobey ohm, s law.